# How to take a gradient of a function in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux

Given that taking gradients is a core idea of machine learning, I am trying to figure out the required code to take a gradient with respect to some function (say `f(x) = 4x^2 + 3x + 2;` and input values in Julia. I looked around but didn't see this mentioned explicitly in the resources I found.

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.233958878.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.222279018.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flux actually has a built in `gradient` function which can be used as follows:

```
julia> using Flux

julia> f(x) = 4x^2 + 3x + 2;

julia> df(x) = gradient(f, x)[1]; # df/dx = 8x + 3

julia> df(2)
19.0
```

where f is the function and x is the input value.

It can even be used to take the 2nd derivative. You can read more about the [gradient function in the Flux.jl docs](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/basics/#Taking-Gradients).